# How can I traverse the DOM to get at a specific element after a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble understanding how to properly utilize .close() to traverse the DOM and make changes to a specific element.

Here is the HTML

```
<li>
    <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
    <div class="shopping-item-controls">
      <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
        <span class="button-label">check</span>
      </button>
      <button class="shopping-item-delete">
        <span class="button-label">delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I need to access the span with class name: shopping-item via jquery when the shopping-item-toggle-button is clicked. I am trying to accomplishing this via .close() and have yet to have any success. It does not seem to be traversing up the DOM as I would expect it to. Here is what I have been trying to no avail.

```
$('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', function(event){

  $(event.currentTarget).closest('span').toggleClass('.shopping-item__checked')

})
```

I think my problem may be using event.currentTarget. As far as I understand that is the button element that was clicked and then .close() should traverse the DOM upward from there to the nearest span but that isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea: using an 'click' eventListener to listen when the user interacts with it, and selecting an element based on the event.target.

The problem is that .closest() appears to look for the nearest Parent, but .shopping-item-toggle is not a child of .shopping-item, but of .shopping-item-controls.

```
<li class="shopping-item-container">       <!-- Parent -->
    <span class="shopping-item">apples</span> <!-- NOT Parent -->
    <div class="shopping-item-controls">      <!-- Parent -->
      <button class="shopping-item-toggle">       <!-- event.target -->
        <span class="button-label">check</span>
      </button>
      <button class="shopping-item-delete">
        <span class="button-label">delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

You could check for the closest closest('li') or add a 'shopping-item-container' (can have any name) class and search for that with closest('shopping-item-container').

```
$('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', function(event){
    $(event.currentTarget).closest('li').toggleClass('.shopping-item__checked')
});
```